# Wordpress + nginx + ALB + SSL -> link issue

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2

This may be more of a Wordpress + Nginx question but I want to double check my config on the AWS side.

I have a new Wordpress installation on EC2, which I set up from scratch (required to). I installed and configured Nginx to sit in front of it. I have an ALB in front of my instance with a DNS record pointing to it (only one static EC2 instance for now).

I have installed an SSL certificate on the ALB using ACM.

I set my SSL listener on the ALB to forward to the lone Wordpress instance on port 80 (Nginx).

Wordpress is running but I can't login and the pages aren't displaying CSS styles. When I view source on the pages, I see the inline image/script/css links using "http" not "https". It seems like this might (now) be an issue in the WP database or in my reverse proxy config.

Also, I can't login via the wp-admin page, the page keeps redirecting me back to itself

Am I mistaking how this should all work? I believe that terminating SSL at the ALB and forwarding all traffic over http (unencrypted) to Nginx is fine. I understand the security implications, the instance can only be reached by the LB via its security group.

I feel like this might be as simple as an Nginx config change.  Or that I might need to set up an SSL certificate on the instance itself.  Or this might require a Wordpress config/db update.

Comment: can you show nginx config file here ?

Comment: Turn off "SSL required" in Wordpress. The correct solution is for WordPress to detect that the client connected to the LB via HTTPS and not redirect the client to HTTPS. The key is to process X-Forwarded-Proto header. Here is a link that will explain in more detail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-proto.